# changing backbone views

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, backbone.js

I have a question about the way backbone handles it views.
Suppose I have the following code:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">
   </div>
</div>
```

After this I change header into a backbone view.

How can I now remove that view from the header div again after I'm done with the view and add ANOTHER view to the same div?

I tried just overwriting the variable the view was stored in. This results in the view being changed to the new one...but it will have all the event handlers of the old one still attached to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement

This won't automatically remove the original div - you'll want to do that yourself somehow, but then by using setElement you'll have the view's element set to whatever you passed it.. and all of the events will be attached as appropriate. Then you'll need to append that element wherever it is that it needs to go.

--- Let's try this again ----

So, first thing to keep in mind is that views reference DOM elements.. they aren't super tightly bound. So, you can work directly with the jquery object under $el.

```
var containerView = new ContainerView();

var headerView = new HeaderView();
var anotherHeaderView = new AnotherHeaderView();

containerView.$el.append(headerView.$el);
containerView.$el.append(anotherHeaderView.$el);

anotherHeaderView.$el.detach();

containerView.$el.prepend(anotherHeaderView.$el);
```

Or you can create methods to control this for you.

```
var ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    addView: function (view) {
        var el = view;
        if(el.$el) { //so you can pass in both dom and backbone views
            el = el.$el;
        }
        this.$el.append(el);
    }
});
```

Maybe setting the views by view order?

```
var ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.types = {};
    },
    addView: function (view, type) {
        var el = view;
        if(el.$el) { //so you can pass in both dom and backbone views
            el = el.$el;
        }
        this.types[type] = el;
        this.resetViews();
    },
    removeView: function (type) {
        delete this.types[type];
        this.resetViews();
    },
    resetViews: function () {
        this.$el.children().detach();
        _.each(['main_header', 'sub_header', 'sub_sub_header'], function (typekey) {
            if(this.types[typekey]) {
                this.$el.append(this.types[typekey]);
            }
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This however doesn't really solve my problem. I don't want to re-use the view on another element. I basically want to just remove the view completely and add another view in the place where the old one was.

Comment: By the way. I tried using view.remove(); But this also removes the complete <div id="header"> so I can't add another view to that div again. I somehow need to find a way to add a view to a <div> and after I'm done with that view, be able to add another view to the same div.

Comment: OK - this is kind of an odd use case. Let me try writing up something else.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the question the wrong way. Suppose I only have one div. This div would have the id 'container'. How could I add multiple views to this container then and be able to remove them again with the container staying intact?

Comment: Ah, there we go - I was just going to ask if that's what you were going for.

Comment: and it would be nice if I could say in what order the views needed to be displayed.

Comment: I didn't have a container view. My container was just a div element. This should maybe solve the problem. I'm gonna try it out now. So there is no way to have anchors in your code which determine where certain views go?

Comment: So something like the last update? You'd have a set of view types, which would be used to construct the order of the views that you'd show?

Comment: That looks exactly to be what I want. I need to find bug in resetViews still and get that out because it complains about 'Cannot read property 'header' of undefined' on the line 'if(this.types[typekey])'. But this is a perfect solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: Doh - sorry, updating. Silly fix. Needed to make sure that the third param of _.each was "this".